# Unity - Sprite not properly loaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I ought to have a normal map of tiles as below:

[image]

But when I load the scene, either switch from another in inspector (e.g. click "scene/menu", then click this scene), or transit into this scene in gameplay (`SceneManager.loadScene`), sprites get invisible randomly.

Each time some of the sprites get invisible, and the next time the invisible ones may not be the same. I suspect it is something with Unity editor, since this happens even when I'm not in playing mode.

In `Debug.Log` I definitely find those sprites (not null). They just don't show up. I have to reload sprites / reload the scene in Unity inspector, but the load doesn't persist.

Neither sprites, SpriteRenderer nor GameObject is `null`.

As below is a snapshot when some sprites invisible (not missing):

[image]

Just click another scene and switch back:

[image]

Comment: To administrators: this post  probably should be in gamedev.stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just accidentally checked in 3D mode, Unity editor is randomizing with `z` axis. The sprites are there, they were just hidden behind background. This can be fixed then.